# Light communication from pc/app to arduino

Tags: serial

I will like to implement a serial communication protocol, using javascript in a mobile browser to make the browser background blink (alternating the color from black to white) according to the bits, to communicate a few bytes to an Arduino using some kind of light sensor (photo diode or resistor) to parse. Electric Imp did something with https://electricimp.com/platform/blinkup/ .

Is there any library or implementation or where to start guide?, if not, how would you implement it?

I fear one of the problems of using a mobile browser with javascript to light-encode the bits will be timing issues, since setTimeInterval is not perfect, I could split the screen, one half blinking continuously (clock) and the other half the data, but that will require two light sensors.

Answer (score 1):

Doing bit stuffing can prevent timing problems when you are sending a lot of `0`s or `1`s in an row. Alternatively use Manchester encoding (slower).

On the browser side, I'd suggest using `<Canvas>`. Combine this with `requestAnimationFrame` which gives you a very accurate timestamp as an argument. Though you have to check for support as older browsers don't support that.

Answer (score 0):

You should investigate communication protocols and encoding techniques that embed the clock signal into the same data stream as the data signal.

One common method is called *[Manchester Coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manchester_code)*.  This entails splitting each bit into two halves.  A 1 sends light followed by dark, and a 0 sends a dark followed by a light.  It's then up to you to work out which transitions are which and where in a bit they occur (is a high transition the start of a 1 or mid-way through a 0?)

Another popular method (used in things like Ethernet) is called 8b/10b.  That involves sending 10 bits to represent every 8 - more efficient than manchester coding (that could be considered 8b/16b) and can be read about here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8b/10b_encoding It's somewhat harder to implement than Manchester Code, so although it's less efficient I'd recommend the simplicity of Manchester Code.